# Why is there no test instrumentation for BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, testing, tdd, broadcastreceiver, instrumentation

Maybe I'm missing something. I want to write test cases for a BroadcastReceiver; specifically, it is for receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED event and setting an alarm for another receiver to handle later; it doesn't seem to be setting it properly, but the point is that I have no obvious way to test it. I can't exactly attach a debugger and wait for BOOT_COMPLETED, and I can't send a fake BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

Why are there instrumentation classes for Activity, Service, and Provider, but not BroadcastReceiver? Any advice for testing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the life cycle for the BroadcastReceiver. It's enough to test it with an AndroidTestCase. In a test case, instantiate your BroadcastReceiver, create whatever Intent you want to send and call onReceive using the Context available from AndroidTestCase or some mock Context.

E.g.

```
public class TestMyBroadcastReceiver extends AndroidTestCase {
  public void testReceive() {
    MyBroadcastReceiver r = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    Intent i = new Intent("MY_ACTION");
    // TODO put extras
    r.onReceive(getContext(), i);
    // TODO query application state to verify results
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple and does the job!

Answer (score 7):

For most cases I agree completely with https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181010/527016

There are however cases when extending `AndroidTestCase` is not suitable (and can cause surprises). In particular, if you are doing more complex integration testing and want to test your `BroadcastReceiver` with an actual `Intent` sent by the system. The main reason is that the `onReceive` method in the broadcast receiver runs on the main application thread while the tests in `AndroidTestCase` run in another thread. This can cause test-related threading issues in code that was not intended to run on multiple threads.

The solution to this is to subclass your test from `InstrumentationTestCase` instead and use the `@UiThreadTest` annotation to make the tests run on the same thread as the `onReceive` method.

For more info (and an example) see:  http://olafurhelgason.blogspot.com/2012/12/threading-and-android-integration.html