# Android Studio- Robotium 5.5.2, problems with broadcasts and other issues with tests

Tags: java, android, android-studio, robotium

I have a project that heavily relies on broadcasts. The application works perfectly when debugging and running normally. However when I try to get robotium working for some black box testing, I'm now seeing strange multiple broadcasts and sections of code that don't seam to execute ( or debugger is not able to break on it). Also it appears to sometimes block some of my methods from executing.

Since it works properly without Robotium running, does anyone know if Robotium has issues with broadcasts, multi-threaded environmentents, or just Android-Studio?

I'm using the ExtSolo library, and am using lines like:

```
    assertTrue("Wait for button (text: Register) failed.",
            soloExt.waitForButton("Register", 200000));
```

and

```
soloExt.sleep(1000);
```

Is it possible that these methods also sleep or stall other working threads?

Any tips or hints would greatly help!

Cheers!

Comment: Use Espresso from Google, it is officially supported.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073982/why-is-there-no-test-instrumentation-for-broadcastreceiver